# Make drupal core independent from public root

Tags: 7

I would like my drupal core independent of my server public root. It makes things neater and separates your Drupal core from any other software that sits at your public root.

I know how to create the symlink, but I can't seem to remember or find the steps for the rest of it.  I believe it involves the httpd.conf file.  Can anyone help me out?  Thanks

I don't want to do it the messier way that involves the .htaccess file.

Comment: This sounds like an Apache question, not a Drupal question.

Comment: Oh yeah man! I wasn't even thinking about that at the time I wrote it.  Could someone migrate this question for me?  Thanks.

Comment: I will ask to the moderators of the other site if they don't have already a similar question.